# does pyomo drop parentheses it sees as unneeded?

Tags: constraints, parentheses, pyomo

I have a constraint (made slightly anonymous):

```
def ex_rule(mod, t, p, s):
return mod.blah[t, p, s] == alpha[s] + \
       beta[s] * ((1-mod.Q[t-Term[s], s]) ** 2) * \
       (1 + (1/2) * ((1-mod.Q[t-2*Term[s], s]) ** 2) *
        (1 + (1/2) * ((1-mod.Q[t-3*Term[s], s]) ** 2)))
model.ex = Constraint(T1, P, set_s, rule=ex_rule)
```

Which generates many lines of constraints in the model file. One specific line is the one below (for t=1, p=1, s=1, Term[1]=3, alpha[1] = .25, and beta[1] = .15).

```
blah[1,1,1] - (0.25 + 0.15*(1 - Q[-2,1])**2*(1 + 0.5*(1 - Q[-5,1])**2*(1 + 0.5*(1 - Q[-8,1])**2)))
```

My main question is could someone confirm that Pyomo is just dropping unnecessary parentheses? And so we can trust PEMDAS is working and so the X**2*Y is done as (X^2)*Y not X^(2*Y)? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I can answer my own question. Pyomo does drop the unneeded parentheses and uses PEMDAS correctly. I tested with a very small problem and things all the results look right. (I varied the parentheses a few different ways including X^(2*Y) the answers were correct)

```
from pyomo.environ import *
model = ConcreteModel()

model.x = Var(initialize=0, bounds=(0, 2))
model.y = Var(initialize=0, bounds=(0, 3))

def obj_rule(mod):
    return ((mod.x**2))*mod.y
model.obj = Objective(rule=obj_rule, sense=maximize)

model.pprint(filename='super_temp_mod.txt')
solver = SolverFactory("ipopt")
results = solver.solve(model, load_solutions=True, tee=True)
model.pprint(filename='super_temp_soln.txt')
```

Answer (score 0):

Pyomo does not "drop" parentheses per se.  What pyomo prints out (for example, through `pprint()`) is an infix string representation of the expression tree that is held in memory.  The routine that generates the string representation follows the normal Python operator precedence rules and inserts parentheses where necessary (actually, there are a few cases where we introduce unnecessary parentheses where the Python operator precedence rules are a bit non-intuitive; see for example this [issue](https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/issues/916) and its corresponding [fix](https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/pull/966)).